# C# ,SQL Do insert these SqlCommands only if txtBasoC.Text > 0 , if not, skip and do to next SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql

Well i have 3 textboxes and each of em is inserting for each row in single click

im trying to insert multiple rows in single click but i dont want them get inserted if the textbox is 0 or null if so just skip it to next rows

here what i've tried i hope you get my idea what im doing

```
    int valueBSC, valuesBSM, valueBSB;

                bool validBSC = int.TryParse(txtBasoC.Text, out valueBSC) && valueBSC > 0;
                bool validBSM = int.TryParse(txtBasoM.Text, out valuesBSM) && valuesBSM > 0;
                bool validBSB = int.TryParse(txtBasoB.Text, out valueBSB) && valueBSB > 0;

//BasoC
            if (!validBSC)
            {
                // prompt the user to do it right
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkmkn2.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", valueBSC);
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@TotalHarga", TbasoC);
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                return;
            }

            if (!validBSM)
            {
                //BasoMie
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
                cmd4.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
                cmd4.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkmkn3.Text);
                cmd4.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", valuesBSM);
                cmd4.Parameters.Add("@TotalHarga", Tbasom);
                cmd4.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
                cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return;
            }
            con.Close();


            if (!validBSB)
            {
                //Baso Bihun
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transaksi (idStruk,Product_Name,Jumlah,TotalHarga,Tanggal_Transaksi) VALUES (@idStruk,@Product_Name,@Jumlah,@TotalHarga,@Tanggal_Transaksi)", con);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@idStruk", lblidstruk.Text);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@Product_Name", chkmkn4.Text);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", valueBSB);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@TotalHarga", Tbasob);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@Tanggal_Transaksi", lbldate.Text);
                cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return;
            }

            con.Close();
```

any idea to change/modify to make same kind like this?

inserting values to evry column with parameters but i have more than 3 rows to get inserted in the same time.. but i if  column Jumlah gets 0 or none just skip the SqlCommand Insert and continue to next one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your textboxes in an array so that you can loop:

```
TextBox[] txts = new TextBox[] {txtBasoC, txtBasoM, txtBasoB};

foreach(TextBox txt in txts)
{
    int result = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(txt.Text, out result) && result > 0)
    {
         //Do your insert
    }   
}
```

Also mind that the way I put them in an array was because I don't know how is your form designed and where textboxes are, for example if they are in a groupbox named `group` you can do this:

```
foreach(TextBox txt in group.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray())
{
    int result = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(txt.Text, out result) && result > 0)
    {
         //Do your insert
    }   
}
```

Comment: my textboxes are located in panel ,alright thanks i'll try that soon as possible

Comment: well panel, groupbox, doesn't differ, I was giving an example of a container.

Comment: do i need make more int? than just int result;? because my insert values per rows are different if that make sense..

Comment: Well no, this line just changes to: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jumlah", result);`

Comment: wait why it doesn't continue after it gets correct? i want it continue to next sql insert command if value of result is > 0 too , so i can get many data rows for each textbox inserted in single click

Comment: @eSooner i didn't understood what you mean, doesn't it loop through all textboxes and insert all?